# When i run "npm run android" or "npx react-native run-android", My emulator keep displaying this error message "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped"

Tags: android-emulator

[Here's the image describing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRaA.png)
I'm using but VScode to create my app.
Even if i tried to manually open it myself, it will keep on displaying the same error on my Emulator.
When i created my first App, i never encountered this types of problem.
but when i uninstalled it and now create this new App project, then my emulator keeps displaying this error message.

I have tried to updates my "Android SDK from version 30.0.3 to version 33.0.0" after running "npx react-native doctor" on my VScode terminal. My first project was created using VScode. Please how can i solve this?